# Creating a Python Wrapper from a JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, uniswap

**Problem Statement**
I wrote a JavaScript code to pull data from Uniswap V3 SDK (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@uniswap/v3-sdk) and I would like to open-source this code on GitHub because currently this isn't possible (for specific use cases). I am not an amazing system designer/programmer so please bare with me (I can only code in Python and barely understand JavaScript).

Essentially, I have a JavaScript code that pulls data and I wanted to wrap it in a Python code, so I can then take the data and do other things with the data (create alerts, flask app, etc.)

I am using Ubuntu, JS6, npm v8.19.2 and Node v16.18.1.

In my research, I found two packages that could help enable me wrapping this JS code in Python:

1. py2js - https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py
2. stpyv8 - https://github.com/cloudflare/stpyv8

**Coding Attempt**

## py2js attempt

This package only works for JS5 and below, not JS6. Here is a quote from the GitHub that helps explain the workaround for this issue (which uses `babel`) https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py:

> JavaScript 6 support was achieved by using Js2Py to translate javascript library called Babel. Babel translates JS 6 to JS 5 and afterwards Js2Py translates JS 5 to Python.

While trying this solution out, I am getting the following error:

```
/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/js2py/es6/__init__.py:10: UserWarning: 
Importing babel.py for the first time - this can take some time. 
Please note that currently Javascript 6 in Js2Py is unstable and slow. Use only for tiny scripts!
  warnings.warn(
/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/js2py/base.py:2854: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 5
  self.pat = re.compile(
Initialised babel!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/main.py", line 104, in <module>
    result = js2py.eval_js6(js)  # executing JavaScript and converting the result to python string 
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/js2py/evaljs.py", line 120, in eval_js6
    return eval_js(js6_to_js5(js))
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/js2py/evaljs.py", line 115, in eval_js
    return e.eval(js)
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/js2py/evaljs.py", line 204, in eval
    self.execute(code, use_compilation_plan=use_compilation_plan)
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/js2py/evaljs.py", line 199, in execute
    exec (compiled, self._context)
  File "<EvalJS snippet>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<EvalJS snippet>", line 3, in PyJs_LONG_0_
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/js2py/base.py", line 949, in __call__
    return self.call(self.GlobalObject, args)
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/js2py/base.py", line 1464, in call
    return Js(self.code(*args))
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/js2py/host/jseval.py", line 17, in Eval
    py_code = translate_js(code.to_string().value, '')
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/js2py/translators/translator.py", line 70, in translate_js
    parsed = parse_fn(js)
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/js2py/translators/translator.py", line 62, in pyjsparser_parse_fn
    return parser.parse(code)
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyjsparser/parser.py", line 3008, in parse
    program = self.parseProgram()
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyjsparser/parser.py", line 2974, in parseProgram
    body = self.parseScriptBody()
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyjsparser/parser.py", line 2963, in parseScriptBody
    statement = self.parseStatementListItem()
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyjsparser/parser.py", line 2110, in parseStatementListItem
    return self.parseStatement()
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyjsparser/parser.py", line 2718, in parseStatement
    self.consumeSemicolon()
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyjsparser/parser.py", line 1120, in consumeSemicolon
    self.throwUnexpectedToken(self.lookahead)
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyjsparser/parser.py", line 1046, in throwUnexpectedToken
    raise self.unexpectedTokenError(token, message)
js2py.internals.simplex.JsException: SyntaxError: Line 34: Unexpected token function
```

#### What have I done to try to fix this?

I have updated node and even downgraded to version 5 as some suggested, but nothing worked.

### JavaScript Code

Here is the JavaScript code (note that you would need an Alchemy API ID to run this script):

```
import { JSBI } from "@uniswap/sdk";
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import * as fs from 'fs';

    // ERC20 json abi file
let ERC20Abi = fs.readFileSync('Erc20.json');
const ERC20 = JSON.parse(ERC20Abi);

    // V3 pool abi json file
let pool = fs.readFileSync('V3PairAbi.json');
const IUniswapV3PoolABI = JSON.parse(pool);

    // V3 factory abi json
let facto = fs.readFileSync('V3factory.json');
const IUniswapV3FactoryABI = JSON.parse(facto);

let NFT = fs.readFileSync('UniV3NFT.json');
const IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI = JSON.parse(NFT);

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(ALCHEMY_API_ID)

    // V3 standard addresses (different for celo)
const factory = "0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984";
const NFTmanager = "0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88";

async function getData(tokenID){
    let FactoryContract = new ethers.Contract(factory, IUniswapV3FactoryABI, provider);

    let NFTContract =  new ethers.Contract(NFTmanager, IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI, provider);
    let position = await NFTContract.positions(tokenID);
    
    let token0contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token0, ERC20, provider);
    let token1contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token1, ERC20, provider);
    let token0Decimal = await token0contract.decimals();
    let token1Decimal = await token1contract.decimals();
    
    let token0sym = await token0contract.symbol();
    let token1sym = await token1contract.symbol();
    
    let V3pool = await FactoryContract.getPool(position.token0, position.token1, position.fee);
    let poolContract = new ethers.Contract(V3pool, IUniswapV3PoolABI, provider);

    let slot0 = await poolContract.slot0();

    
    let pairName = token0sym +"/"+ token1sym;
    
    let dict = {"SqrtX96" : slot0.sqrtPriceX96.toString(), "Pair": pairName, "T0d": token0Decimal, "T1d": token1Decimal, "tickLow": position.tickLower, "tickHigh": position.tickUpper, "liquidity": position.liquidity.toString()}

    return dict
}


const Q96 = JSBI.exponentiate(JSBI.BigInt(2), JSBI.BigInt(96));
const MIN_TICK = -887272;
const MAX_TICK = 887272;

function getTickAtSqrtRatio(sqrtPriceX96){
    let tick = Math.floor(Math.log((sqrtPriceX96/Q96)**2)/Math.log(1.0001));
    return tick;
}

async function getTokenAmounts(liquidity,sqrtPriceX96,tickLow,tickHigh,token0Decimal,token1Decimal){
    let sqrtRatioA = Math.sqrt(1.0001**tickLow).toFixed(18);
    let sqrtRatioB = Math.sqrt(1.0001**tickHigh).toFixed(18);
    let currentTick = getTickAtSqrtRatio(sqrtPriceX96);
    let sqrtPrice = sqrtPriceX96 / Q96;
    let amount0wei = 0;
    let amount1wei = 0;
    if(currentTick <= tickLow){
        amount0wei = Math.floor(liquidity*((sqrtRatioB-sqrtRatioA)/(sqrtRatioA*sqrtRatioB)));
    }
    if(currentTick > tickHigh){
        amount1wei = Math.floor(liquidity*(sqrtRatioB-sqrtRatioA));
    }
    if(currentTick >= tickLow && currentTick < tickHigh){ 
        amount0wei = Math.floor(liquidity*((sqrtRatioB-sqrtPrice)/(sqrtPrice*sqrtRatioB)));
        amount1wei = Math.floor(liquidity*(sqrtPrice-sqrtRatioA));
    }
    
    let amount0Human = (amount0wei/(10**token0Decimal)).toFixed(token0Decimal);
    let amount1Human = (amount1wei/(10**token1Decimal)).toFixed(token1Decimal);

    console.log("Amount Token0 wei: "+amount0wei);
    console.log("Amount Token1 wei: "+amount1wei);
    console.log("Amount Token0 : "+amount0Human);
    console.log("Amount Token1 : "+amount1Human);
    return [amount0wei, amount1wei]
}

async function start(positionID){
    let data = await getData(positionID);
    let tokens = await getTokenAmounts(data.liquidity, data.SqrtX96, data.tickLow, data.tickHigh, data.T0d, data.T1d);
}

start(273381)
// Also it can be used without the position data if you pull the data it will work for any range
getTokenAmounts(12558033400096537032, 20259533801624375790673555415)
```

### Python Code

Here is the python code I wrote using the js2py package. To save space, I removed the JS Code in the `js` variable below, but you can copy it from above and place it in the triple quotes:

```
import js2py

js = """
<<< JS CODE COPIED HERE >>>
""".replace("document.write", "return ")

result = js2py.eval_js6(js)  # executing JavaScript and converting the result to python string
```

One other note, you will need to install babel as well to make it work. Babel will help convert the code from JS6 to JS5.

## stpyv8 attempt

This package is maintained by Cloudflare, which makes this a much more attractive approach, but I am having difficulty installing the pyv8 package on my machine.

I was able to successfully run:

```
sudo apt install python3 python3-dev build-essential libboost-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-python-dev libboost-iostreams-dev
```

The probem is that I now need to run `setup.py`, which I can't find. I also below, if you look at the pyv8 installation I tried below, it does it automatically, but it throws an error. Seems like I am getting stuck at trying to run `setup.py`

## pyv8 attempt (alternative to stpyv8 I believe)

https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyv8/

When I run `pip3 install -v pyv8`, I get the following error:

```
Using pip 22.0.2 from /home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
Collecting pyv8
  Using cached PyV8-0.5.zip (22 kB)
  Running command python setup.py egg_info
  running egg_info
  creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-g__o7shf/PyV8.egg-info
  writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-g__o7shf/PyV8.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-g__o7shf/PyV8.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-g__o7shf/PyV8.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-g__o7shf/PyV8.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-g__o7shf/PyV8.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-g__o7shf/PyV8.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyv8, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyv8
  Running command Running setup.py install for pyv8
  running install
  /home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
    warnings.warn(
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10
  copying PyV8.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10
  running build_ext
  building '_PyV8' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -Ilib/python/inc -Ilib/boost/inc -Ilib/v8/inc -I/home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/Context.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/src/Context.o
  In file included from src/Wrapper.h:8,
                   from src/Context.h:7,
                   from src/Context.cpp:1:
  src/Exception.h:6:10: fatal error: v8.h: No such file or directory
      6 | #include <v8.h>
        |          ^~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for pyv8 did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/bin/python3 -u -c '
  exec(compile('"'"''"'"''"'"'
  # This is <pip-setuptools-caller> -- a caller that pip uses to run setup.py
  #
  # - It imports setuptools before invoking setup.py, to enable projects that directly
  #   import from `distutils.core` to work with newer packaging standards.
  # - It provides a clear error message when setuptools is not installed.
  # - It sets `sys.argv[0]` to the underlying `setup.py`, when invoking `setup.py` so
  #   setuptools doesn'"'"'t think the script is `-c`. This avoids the following warning:
  #     manifest_maker: standard file '"'"'-c'"'"' not found".
  # - It generates a shim setup.py, for handling setup.cfg-only projects.
  import os, sys, tokenize
  
  try:
      import setuptools
  except ImportError as error:
      print(
          "ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in "
          "the build environment.",
          file=sys.stderr,
      )
      sys.exit(1)
  
  __file__ = %r
  sys.argv[0] = __file__
  
  if os.path.exists(__file__):
      filename = __file__
      with tokenize.open(__file__) as f:
          setup_py_code = f.read()
  else:
      filename = "<auto-generated setuptools caller>"
      setup_py_code = "from setuptools import setup; setup()"
  
  exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))
  '"'"''"'"''"'"' % ('"'"'/tmp/pip-install-b9d0zoul/pyv8_c9dfd2e4ec0e4c66a2bff47f44972004/setup.py'"'"',), "<pip-setuptools-caller>", "exec"))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-pel12p8h/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/bobby/uni_balances/uni_venv/include/site/python3.10/pyv8
  cwd: /tmp/pip-install-b9d0zoul/pyv8_c9dfd2e4ec0e4c66a2bff47f44972004/
  Running setup.py install for pyv8 ... error
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyv8

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

## Conclusion

I am not married to using the two options I mentioned above, but I would like to pull the data into Python from the JS code.

Also this is the output from the JS code that I need to port over into Python:
[image]